# Strange behaviour of listview position onlicklistener

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that displays food orders for a certain restaurant. When the user clicks on one of the listview items, it is supposed to show a toast of the position of the item clicked and also the order id of the food order. For some reason the wrong position is displayed.

PendingOrders.java. Data is loaded from firebase

```
public class PendingOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
ArrayList<OrderDetails> activeorders = new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();
private OrdersAdapter adapter;
ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pending_orders);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pendinglistview);
    adapter = new OrdersAdapter(this,activeorders);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    ValueEventListener listen = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            OrderDetails order = dataSnapshot.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
            String str = order.UserId;

            if (str.equals("abc")) {
                boolean add = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < activeorders.size(); i++) {
                    String checking = activeorders.get(i).OrderId;
                    if (checking.equals(order.OrderId)) {
                        add = false;
                    }
                }

                if (add = true) {
                    activeorders.add(order);
                    ((OrdersAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    };



    for (int i=1; i<=4;i++) {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Active Orders")
                .child(Integer.toString(i));
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listen);
    }



}
```

}

OrdersAdapter.java

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<OrderDetails> activeorders;
Button confirmationbutton;

public OrdersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderDetails> activeorders){
    this.context = context;
    this.activeorders = activeorders;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  activeorders.size() ;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return activeorders.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.orderlistview, null);

        viewHolder.mdtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mdtitle);
        confirmationbutton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confirmationbutton);
        confirmationbutton.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.switchbutton = (MultiStateToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mstb_multi_id);
        viewHolder.switchbutton.setElements(R.array.planets_array,0);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Semibold.ttf");

        viewHolder.mdtitle.setTypeface(font);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    }

    confirmationbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
            OrderDetails orders = (OrderDetails)getItem(pos);
            String orderingid = orders.OrderId;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+ Integer.toString(pos)+" orderid : "+orderingid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DatabaseReference mDatabase;
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mDatabase.child("Active Orders").child(orderingid).child("Status").setValue("Cooking");

            FrameLayout vwParentRow = (FrameLayout)v.getParent();
            Button btnChild = (Button)vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
            MultiStateToggleButton btnchild2 = (MultiStateToggleButton)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);
            btnChild.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnchild2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    OrderDetails orders = (OrderDetails)getItem(position);
    viewHolder.mdtitle.setText(orders.foodname);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView mdtitle;
    Button confirmationbutton;
    MultiStateToggleButton switchbutton;

}
```

}

[Screenshot of listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU5pW.png)

**Expected Output:**

Clicking button of pizza : Position 0 orderid 3

Clicking button of soupp : Position 1 orderid 4

**Current Output:**

Clicking button of pizza : Position 0 orderid 3

Clicking button of soupp : Position 0 orderid 3

This is if I wait for the data to be loaded in and click the buttons straight away. I have noticed that if I wait for data load, then press the back button and get back into the activity again, then the output will be correct. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **OnClickListener** should be out side of set and get of *ViewHolder* pattern in **getView**

*Why strange?*

> Your button click Listener will only attached in 0th position when
>   convertView will be **null**. after onwords convertView will be filled and
>   listener would not attached for that position like 1th, 2th and so on.

see updated *getView*

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {    
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();    
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.orderlistview, null);
        confirmationbutton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confirmationbutton);
        confirmationbutton.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

       viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

   final int pos = position;
   confirmationbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            OrderDetails orders = (OrderDetails)getItem(pos);
            String orderingid = orders.OrderId;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Position :"+ Integer.toString(pos)+" orderid : "+orderingid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
    });

    OrderDetails orders = (OrderDetails)getItem(pos);
    viewHolder.mdtitle.setText(orders.foodname);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to move the code block according to your suggestion but still suffering from the same problem.

Comment: posted the whole pendingorders class too just in case

Comment: I think you are trying with wrong `positon` here `Integer pos = (Integer)v.getTag();` it should be getview's pos

Comment: Thanks, the updated answer works, ur explanation of the listener's position is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `setOnClickListener` out of the `if(convertview == null)`statment.